# Adding to numpy.nextafter() float returns unexpected result

Tags: python, numpy, python-2.7, ieee-754

According to Wolfram Alpha, this is true for `x > 2`.

```
6.0/(x+16) > 2.0/(x+4)
```

To get the smallest possible `x`, I'm using `numpy.nextafter()`.

```
>>> from numpy import nextafter
>>> x = nextafter(2,2+1)
>>> x
2.0000000000000004
```

However.

```
>>> 6.0/(x+16) > 2.0/(x+4)
False
```

Curiously.

```
>>> x+1
3.0000000000000004
>>> x+4
6.0
```

So how do I get the actual smallest possible `x > 2` for this case?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

x = 2.0
while True:
    if 6.0/(x+16) > 2.0/(x+4): break
    x = np.nextafter(x, x+1)   
print(repr(x))
```

yields

```
2.0000000000000009
```

---

How floats are handled in CPython depends on the underlying C library. Most C libraries implement the [IEEE 754 Standard for Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point#Standard). However, "the IEEE standard does not guarantee that the same program will deliver identical results on all conforming systems." (See p. 249 of "What Every Computer Scientist Should Know about Floating-Point Arithmetic" ([PDF](http://www.validlab.com/goldberg/paper.pdf)) and also [PEP 754](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0754/)).

To be able to predict the value `x` without iteration, one would have to study how floating point arithmetic is done (ibid ([PDF](http://www.validlab.com/goldberg/paper.pdf))), write down `x` in its general binary format,

[image]

substitute this into the inequality

```
6.0/(x+16) > 2.0/(x+4)
```

and trace through the floating point arithmetic algorithms to solve for the digits `dᵢ` corresponding to the smallest float that satisifies the inequality.

Comment: Note that the hex value is 0x1.0000000000002p+1, which is 2.000000000000000888... `numpy.float64` and Python `float` differ in the string representation of this float. Python chooses the shortest decimal string that rounds back to the original value, which is 2.000000000000001. This is just a cosmetic difference.

Comment: This answers the specific question, but I'm interested in a more general answer.

Comment: Thanks for the extended answer. In my case `1+1e-10` is precise enough, but I was curious whether a simple general formula is available. For me this is too complicated, so iteration seems the best and easiest choice.

Answer (score 3):

unutbu's method should be pretty general.  If what you're asking for is why it doesn't work after the first iteration, the answer is because of rounding.  When you use `np.nextafter`, you're working at the limit of precision, so any arithmetic operation after that can't be trusted implicitly.  In your case, it's probably the `+ 16` that's the problem.  16 is a couple exponent bits up from 2, so you're going to lose that increment to finite precision.  In this case, it takes one extra increment to get that sum to round up instead of down.